# difference between rank and skill group in csgo

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was wondering what the difference between a rank and a skill group is, or maybe it's the same thing. I'm not a pro at csgo and recently ranked up to Private 4, but i have to win 8 more competitive games to get my skill group. so what's the difference between those two and how do i go from ex, silver 1 to silver 2. is it amount of wins and losses or is it xp?

obs. i'm new at csgo, so still no pro at the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between rank and skill group. The skill group in CSGO is how you match up to other players. The rank("level") however, is essentially irrelevant, the only thing that matters about it is you have to reach Rank 3 to play competitive. The only other way competitive is linked to your rank is that it yields larger amounts of EXP due to the longer play time. Your skill group is the amount of wins and losses in the competitive playmode.